# Embed resource list within trigger to apply conditional theme

Tags: wpf, xaml

So I'm working with a wpf application for the first time and have run into a stumbling block.

I'm working with themes from a third party (actipro) and I can set the individual properties within that theme to whatever I want like so

```
<Style.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush   x:Key="{x:Static themes:AssetResourceKeys.ExpanderHeaderBackgroundNormalBrushKey}" Color="Yellow" />
</Style.Resources>
```

What I want to do, actually, is place that declaration inside a trigger like so

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
              <SolidColorBrush   x:Key="{x:Static themes:AssetResourceKeys.ExpanderHeaderBackgroundNormalBrushKey}" Color="Yellow" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

But this, of course is illegal syntax.

I know I can set conditional styles like this

```
<Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
        </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

or even like this

```
<Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static themes:AssetResourceKeys.ExpanderHeaderBackgroundNormalBrushKey}}" />
        </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

But this sets the background to the color defined by the resource.  That's not what I'm after.
I need to set the ExpanderHeaderBackground, Which is not an available property for the setter.

In my mind, it would seem logical to be able to define the resources themselves within the trigger.  Then they would only apply if some condition is met.  Obviously that's not how wpf works.

Any one know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the resource in your Style resources but not in the Trigger itself.

```
<Style TargetType="Control">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static themes:AssetResourceKeys.ExpanderHeaderBackgroundNormalBrushKey}" Color="Yellow" />
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource themes:AssetResourceKeys.ExpanderHeaderBackgroundNormalBrushKey}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The Trigger itself does not provide specific resources. If what you want to achieve is overriding a specific resource based on its resource key, and depending on a UI behavior (like a MouseOver for example) you'll have to do that using code behind.

Edit: I'm not familiar with Actipro, but do they suggest customizing their theme by overriding resources base on resource keys ? It's not considered as a very good practice as it won't produce reliable results.

Comment: I don't want to override the resources, I want to apply them conditionally.  I've tried the code you've posted previously, but it's not what I'm after, unfortunately.

Comment: I think I got your functional requirement ^^ But actually, doing <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static themes:AssetResourceKeys.ExpanderHeaderBackgroundNormalBrushKey}"> , even if it doesnt look like it, is an override. If you want to apply the brush conditionally, you have to find where it is used in the control template, and change it there thanks to a Trigger :)

Comment: It's really just a validation scenario, that would be really easy to handle in a web application.  But changing the look of this third party control conditionally seems much more difficult than it should be.

Comment: Could you tell me what is the control you use ?